# About the zeros of $f_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-z}$.

Tags: roots

Let $z$ be a complex number. Consider $f_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n  k^{-z}$.

Now I wonder : Are there infinitely many positive integer $n$ such that there exists a $z$ with $f_n(z)=0$ and $Re(z)>1$ ?

I know that such $z$ exists for $n=13$.

Comment: I assume that the lower limit is $1,$ not $0.$

Comment: I don't understand what the "I know it is true for $n=13$" means in relation with your question above. Should it be a "I know that such a $z$ exists for $n=13$" or what?

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull comments , I edited.

Comment: Use `\sum` for sums, not `\Sigma`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you read this article by [P. Borwein et al](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-16/issue-1/Zeros-of-Partial-Summs-of-the-Riemann-Zeta-Function/em/1175789799.full). (Experimental math, 2007), as well as [this followup by Gonek and Ledoan.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0019)